# How Can I make height a proportion of width in opposite direction in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I would like to change the width of some element according to the height of the page. if height gets smaller, the width of those elements gets larger!

Comment: like width:calc(100% - 50vh) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [viewport-percentage lengths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length), specifically the **vh** (viewport height) unit to scale any property of an element based on the height of the window.

For example, this element will have its width at 75% of the browser's height:

```
.scale {
  width: 75vh;
}
```

To do the inverse of this as you stated ("if height gets smaller, the width of those elements gets larger"), you could use **[calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** like so:

```
.scale {
  width: calc(100% - 25vh);
}
```